# Determine if this series : $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this infinite series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}$$ I am really confused on where to begin with, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Limit comparison test?

Comment: Which one? I thought about comparing it with $1/n^2$ but i get basically nowere

Comment: Your sum does not converge

Comment: The terms are asymptotic to $1/\ln(n)$ which is larger than, for example, $1/\sqrt n$.

Comment: Nice!! There was the trick! Thank you i didnt do the basic thing about doing the limit of the general term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{n}{(n+1)ln(n+1)} \sim \frac1{\ln n}$$

therefore the given series diverges by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{\ln n}$ since

$$\frac1{\ln n}>\frac1n$$

and then $\sum \frac1{\ln n}$ diverges by comparison with $\sum \frac1{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_n{n\over{ln(n+1)}}=+\infty$ and $\sum{1\over{n+1}}$ diverges so the serie diverges.

You can also says that ${{n\over {(n+1)\ln(n+1)}}\over {1\over {n+1}}}$
$={n\over{\ln(n+1)}}$ and $\lim_n{n\over{\ln(n+1)}}=+\infty$ the comparison test implies that the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

From $\ln(n+1)<n+1$ and $n>\dfrac{n+1}{2}$ then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}>\dfrac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: Wel, $n\geq \tfrac{n+1}2$ since $1=\tfrac{1+1}2$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=\dfrac{n}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)} > \dfrac{1}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}\implies \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ge\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{1}{n\ln n}$. Now use the Cauchy Condensation Test to the right series we have: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^n\cdot \dfrac{1}{2^n\ln (2^n)}= \dfrac{1}{\ln 2}\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n} = \infty$. This shows the former series diverges....
**Note:** You can solve it by first use comparison and integral test.